# Sequelize 5 belongs to relation is not working

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have 2 models separately named as "User" and "Test" in sequelize 5. Belongs To relation 
is given in Test model and it has userId from User model.

I have given the Belongs to relation in Test Model as below.
**Test Model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Test = sequelize.define('Test', {
        testId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            validate: {
                isInt: true
            }
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
        },
        userId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        }
    }, {
            tableName: 'tests'
        });
    Test.associate = (model) => {
        Test.belongsTo(model.User, {
            as: 'User',
            foreignKey: 'userId',
            targetKey: 'userId'
        });
    };
return Test;
};
```

**User Model**

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        userId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            validate: {
                isInt: true
            }
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    });

    console.log(sequelize.models);
    return User;
};
```

**ORM Query to find test model data as below**

```
import db from '../../config/sequelize';
const { User, Test } = db;
Test.findAll({
        limit,
        include: [
            {
                model: User,
                as: 'User'
            }
        ]
    })
```

**Error Message: User is not associated to Test**

Any idea how to associate it to get the user data in test ?

Comment: `User` table definition has `userId` field ? and `User.hasMany(model.Test {})` method ?

Comment: Yes, user model has userId field. but why User.hasMany should be given? here

Comment: I tried User.associate = (model) => {
        console.log('************************************');
        model.User.hasMany(model.User, {
            foreignKey: 'userId'
        });
    }; 
Still not working

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Here is a working example using `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import assert from 'assert';

const Test = sequelize.define(
  'Test',
  {
    testId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      validate: {
        isInt: true,
      },
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
  },
  { tableName: 'tests' },
);

const User = sequelize.define(
  'User',
  {
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      validate: {
        isInt: true,
      },
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { tableName: 'users' },
);

Test.belongsTo(User, { as: 'User', foreignKey: 'userId', targetKey: 'userId' });

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await Test.create(
      { username: 'vans', User: { username: 'nike', createdAt: new Date() } },
      { include: [{ model: User, as: 'User' }] },
    );

    // test
    const result = await Test.findAll({
      limit: 1,
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          as: 'User',
        },
      ],
    });
    console.log(result);
    assert.equal(result.length, 1, 'should query one data row');
    assert.equal(result[0].testId, 1);
    assert.equal(result[0].username, 'vans');
    assert.equal(result[0].userId, 1);
    assert.equal(result[0].User.userId, 1);
    assert.equal(result[0].User.username, 'nike');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution results:

```sh
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "users" ("userId","username","createdAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "tests" ("testId","username","userId") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): SELECT "Test"."testId", "Test"."username", "Test"."userId", "User"."userId" AS "User.userId", "User"."username" AS "User.username", "User"."createdAt" AS "User.createdAt" FROM "tests" AS "Test" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" AS "User" ON "Test"."userId" = "User"."userId" LIMIT 1;
[ Test {
    dataValues: { testId: 1, username: 'vans', userId: 1, User: [User] },
    _previousDataValues: { testId: 1, username: 'vans', userId: 1, User: [User] },
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions:
     { timestamps: false,
       validate: {},
       freezeTableName: true,
       underscored: false,
       paranoid: false,
       rejectOnEmpty: false,
       whereCollection: null,
       schema: null,
       schemaDelimiter: '',
       defaultScope: {},
       scopes: {},
       indexes: [],
       name: [Object],
       omitNull: false,
       tableName: 'tests',
       sequelize: [Sequelize],
       hooks: {} },
    _options:
     { isNewRecord: false,
       _schema: null,
       _schemaDelimiter: '',
       include: [Array],
       includeNames: [Array],
       includeMap: [Object],
       includeValidated: true,
       attributes: [Array],
       raw: true },
    isNewRecord: false,
    User:
     User {
       dataValues: [Object],
       _previousDataValues: [Object],
       _changed: {},
       _modelOptions: [Object],
       _options: [Object],
       isNewRecord: false } } ]
```

data rows in the database:

```sh
=# select * from tests;
 testId | username | userId
--------+----------+--------
      1 | vans     |      1
(1 row)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from users;
 userId | username |         createdAt
--------+----------+----------------------------
      1 | nike     | 2020-03-11 07:12:24.782+00
(1 row)
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/node-sequelize-examples/tree/master/src/examples/stackoverflow/59653217